# Check if a coordinate is inside a polygon in flutter using google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-flutter

I using google_maps_flutter library on my flutter project, I created a polygon but i wanted to check if a coordinate is within a polygon... how can i do this?

That is google widget

```
GoogleMap(
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
    myLocationEnabled: true,
    mapToolbarEnabled: false,
    polygons: myPolygon(),
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
    onCameraIdle: _onCameraIdle,
),
```

Please how can i check if a coordinate is within the polygon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `PolyUtil.containsLocation` method on the [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility#poly-encoding). Here is the reference [documentation](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/).

And, with flutter, you can use all PolyUtil methods that are available in google map utility class PolyUtil by using the `google_map_polyutil 1.0.0` package that can be found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyutil).

I hope this helps!