# Flutter Google Map how to check if user is in marker rectangle region

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I am using Google Maps, and want to be able to detect if a user is in the rectangle of a Marker (placed on a map), using the user's current location. how i can get the hole rectangle coordinates and check whether the my user are in the specific rectangle are not i am using it for Attendance project by the way i am using flutter for android app

Comment: you mean is you draw some line on map through coordiante and when some user came in the specfic coordinate then you triger some thing ..like his attendence automatically going on server..? or please correct  me if i'm wrong

Comment: yes I want to draw a rectangle around a hospital or school building and when students/Doctor come to that building they can mark his attendance or may be automatically and I ill do some more stuff

Comment: Other possible duplicates: [Check if a coordinate is inside a polygon in flutter using google_maps_flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086855/check-if-a-coordinate-is-inside-a-polygon-in-flutter-using-google-maps-flutter), [Check if the point is within the Google Maps polygon in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67462271/check-if-the-point-is-within-the-google-maps-polygon-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution
Use this package

```
maps_toolkit: ^2.0.0
```

first make your googleMap Class like this

```
 import 'package:maps_toolkit/maps_toolkit.dart'
        
        class _GoogleMapsWidgetState extends State<GoogleMapsWidget> {
var latitude;
var longitude;
    
          Set<Polygon> _polygons = HashSet<Polygon>();
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            polygoan();
        
            // TODO: implement initState
            super.initState();
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            print("init map");
            return new Scaffold(
                body: Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  // circles: circles,
                  polygons: _polygons,
    
                  gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                   new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => new 
                   EagerGestureRecognizer(),),
                  ].toSet(),
                  cameraMove:  (position) {
 
                           latitude = position.target.latitude;                                
                           longitude = position.target.longitude;

                         },
                  cameraIdle:() async {
                            
                              if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                                
                                  distanceBetweenPoints = PolygonUtil.containsLocation(LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                    [
                                      LatLng(24.8671979,66.9685133),
                                      LatLng(24.8509609,66.7337653),
                                      LatLng(24.9009609,66.7337653),
                                      LatLng(24.9209609,66.7337653),
                                      LatLng(24.9734838,66.9055773),
                                      LatLng(25.0585608,67.0920403),
                                      LatLng(24.9809088,67.2108533),
                                      LatLng(25.0461688,67.2740133),
                                      LatLng(25.1631338,67.3294933),
                                      LatLng(25.153956, 67.365219),
                                      LatLng(24.9961038,67.3152423),
                                                                  //bahria town
    
                                      LatLng(24.9669878,67.2399053),
                                      LatLng(24.8771229,67.1956623),
                                      LatLng(24.8168969,67.2279713),
                                      LatLng(24.8009849,67.1316243),
                                      LatLng(24.7835109,67.1362163),
                                      LatLng(24.7791219,67.1220993),
                                      LatLng(24.8292699,67.0936673),
                                      LatLng(24.8498649,67.0938363),
                                      LatLng(24.8451169,67.0843003),
                                      LatLng(24.8206559,67.0833513),
                                      LatLng(24.8031969,67.0757973),
                                      LatLng(24.7933619,67.0775643),
                                      LatLng(24.7608529,67.1010113),
                                      LatLng(24.7490799,67.0773103),
                                      LatLng(24.7967999,67.0314263),
                                   ],false
                                 );
    //now  here you can handle the app if he is in the given coordinate or not
                                 if(distanceBetweenPoints == true)
                                 {
                                  // if he is in the region
                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                        
    
                                 }
    
                              }
                            },
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    print("after Map");
                    // controller.setMapStyle(
                    //     );
                    widget.completer.complete(controller);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ));
          }
        
          void polygoan() {
            _polygons.add(Polygon(
              fillColor: Colors.transparent,
              polygonId: PolygonId('polygonId'),
              points: [
                LatLng(24.8671979, 66.9685133),
                LatLng(24.8509609, 66.7337653),
                LatLng(24.9009609, 66.7337653),
                LatLng(24.9209609, 66.7337653),
                LatLng(24.9734838, 66.9055773),
                LatLng(25.0585608, 67.0920403),
                LatLng(24.9809088, 67.2108533),
                LatLng(25.0461688, 67.2740133),
                LatLng(25.1631338, 67.3294933),
                LatLng(25.153956, 67.365219),
                LatLng(24.9961038, 67.3152423),
        
        //bahria town
                LatLng(24.9669878, 67.2399053),
                LatLng(24.8771229, 67.1956623),
                LatLng(24.8168969, 67.2279713),
                LatLng(24.8009849, 67.1316243),
                LatLng(24.7835109, 67.1362163),
                LatLng(24.7791219, 67.1220993),
                LatLng(24.8292699, 67.0936673),
                LatLng(24.8498649, 67.0938363),
                LatLng(24.8451169, 67.0843003),
                LatLng(24.8206559, 67.0833513),
                LatLng(24.8031969, 67.0757973),
                LatLng(24.7933619, 67.0775643),
                LatLng(24.7608529, 67.1010113),
                LatLng(24.7490799, 67.0773103),
                LatLng(24.7967999, 67.0314263),
              ],
              strokeWidth: 3,
              strokeColor: Colors.redAccent,
            ));
          }
        }
```

hope this will answer your question..it its help you mark this answer as marked to help other

Comment: Where is PolygoneUtil ?

Comment: its coming from this package maps_toolkit: ^2.0.0

Comment: But again this will check for the complete coordinate match. If there slightly difference in coordinates of user's location, It will return false. Let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: It will just check that you're in the given coordinate or not. and just one thing these given coordinate make a boundary wall